# TypeError: $controller is not a function - angularjs with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to set up a test for AngularJS app using Jasmine. It follows the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller) but is a bit simpler. The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5ebb55f/) has the following code:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "hello";
  }]);

describe('My controller', function() {
  var $controller;
  module('myapp');
  inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;

  });

  it('greets', function() {
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
    expect($scope.greeting).toEqual('hello');
  })

});
```

And Jasmine reports an error: `TypeError: $controller is not a function.`

How to correct the code to get rid of this error and be able to test the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to instantiate the app module and inject `$controller` for each test using `beforeEach` blocks:

```
describe('My controller', function() {
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myapp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('greets', function() {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
        expect($scope.greeting).toEqual('hello');
    })

});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/f5ebb55f/6/

Comment: and you should make sure that the source code of the needed controllers are loaded in your karma config in the "files" section. The name of the module that you load in the `beforeEach(module('modulename'));` command in the test itself must match the module name that you use in your controller source file e.g. `angular.module('modulename', []).controller...`